# The second dropdown value for multiple dropdown value NOT SAVE in database using laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

Hye everyone! First of all, my coding all about dynamic dropdown value, the issues now is the second dropdown value is not save inside the database. Which part did I missed or wrong?

View:-

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="shiftPatternID" name="inputShiftPatternID" id="inputShiftPatternID" required style="width: 100%">
        <option value="" hidden disabled selected>Please Select</option>
        @foreach ($shiftpattern as $singleshiftpattern)
            <option value="{{ $singleshiftpattern->id }}">{{ $singleshiftpattern->id }} - {{ $singleshiftpattern->code }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="sapCode" name="inputSapCode" id="inputSapCode" required style="width: 100%">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">Please Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**View for second dropdown using jquery script:-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change','.shiftPatternID',function() {
        var cat_id=$(this).val();
        var div=$(this).parent().parent().parent();
        var op=" ";

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '{!! URL::to('findSapCode') !!}',
            data: {
                'id':cat_id
            },
            
            success: function(data) {
                op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>Please Select</option>';
                for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                    op += '<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].code+' - '+data[i].description+'</option>';
                }

                $('.sapCode').html('') ; 
                $('.sapCode').append(op);
            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller:-**

```
public function store(Request $req)
{
    $var_shift_pattern_id = $req ->inputShiftPatternID;
    $var_sap_code = $req ->inputSapCode;

    $usp_var = new UserShiftPattern;
    $usp_var-> shift_pattern_id = $var_shift_pattern_id;
    $usp_var-> sap_code = $var_sap_code;
    $usp_var->save();
    $execute = UserHelper::LogUserAct($req, "User Work Schedule Management", "Create User Work Schedule " .$req->inputUserID);
    $feedback_text = "Successfully created User Work Schedule ".$req->inputUserID.".";
    $feedback_title = "Successfully Created";

    return redirect(route('usp.index', [], false))
        ->with([
            'feedback' => true,
            'feedback_text' => $feedback_text,
            'feedback_title' => $feedback_title
        ]);
}
```

**Routes:-**

```
Route::get('/findSapCode','Admin\UserShiftPatternController@findSapCode');
Route::get('/admin/usershiftpattern', 'Admin\UserShiftPatternController@index')->name('usp.index');
Route::post('/admin/usershiftpattern/add', 'Admin\UserShiftPatternController@store')->name('usp.store');
Route::post('/admin/usershiftpattern', 'Admin\UserShiftPatternController@index')->name('usp.index');
```

Comment: can you provide blade template code

Comment: @John Lobo already edit my question

Comment: can you show db structure as well or try to dd($req->all())

Comment: where should i put dd($req->all())?

Comment: before $var_shift_pattern_id = $req ->inputShiftPatternID; this

Comment: $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('shift_pattern_id');
            $table->dateTime('start_date')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('end_date')->nullable();
            $table->string('sap_code', 20);
            $table->integer('created_by')->default(0);
            $table->string('source','5')->default('SAP');
            $table->dateTime('upd_sap')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233637/discussion-between-daisy-and-john-lobo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with option value wrongly passed in jquery.It should be `data[i].code` instead of `data[i].id`

```
op+='<option value="'+data[i].code+'">'+data[i].code+" "+data[i].description+'</option>'
```

Also you might need to update query as well to show description

```
$data=ShiftPattern::select('code','id','description')->where('id',$request->id)->take(100)->get();
```